# FINDSTR in batch file to search some directories and using a file to input the search strings

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, findstr

I can only use Windows command line commands for this as program is running forensics in a Windows batch file only to extract information.

I want the user to be able to populate a file with keywords (strings) as `keywords.txt` that they want to search for.

I only want to search some directories which will popular locations to store user items hence `directorylist.txt`.

I then want to output any findings into a text file `Found_Keywords.txt`.

I have been using

```
FINDSTR /R /I /M /G:C\Users\Admin1\Desktop\Keywords.txt /D:C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\DirectoryList.txt >C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\Found_Keywords.txt
Pause
```

This doesn't appear to work. I have tried sampling the code in other formats and running tests where I search for a string against a given file that contains that string and still no results.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please.

In essence I want someone else to be able to perform keyword searches on a computer against user generated files such as word docs, text, docs and filenames.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please.

Comment: You know that **DOS** is an OS from the 1980s, don't you? so I assume you mean Windows command prompt (`cmd`)...

Comment: @Rich I think there is no chance to do this with a batch file because Microsoft Word document files are binary files whereby `*.doc` (Word 97-2003) contain the text at least as text encoded in ANSI or UTF-16, but `*.docx` (Word 2007+) are ZIP compressed files with text being in stored file no text anymore, but a compressed data stream. So you need Windows Desktop search, or Google Desktop search, or shareware tools like UltraFinder or Total Commander (all GUI applications) which support searching for multiple strings in text and Microsoft Office files (decoded in memory by those applications).